# how to populate drop down list in jq-grid filters using struts2-jqgrid-plugin

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2-jqgrid-plugin to so show data in Grid-view, I want to have filters on the grid. I am able to show filters on Grid, I am also able to the data suppose name of the users on the column but data is not displayed in drop-down list but in a json-string format like this string `{"helpDeskUsers":"success","userList":{"departments":null,"helper_name":"anand","helper_value":null,"user_level":null},`

**My jqgrid is**

```
<s:url var="fillUser" action="getAllUsers" />
      <sjg:grid
            id="gridtable"

            filter="true"

           filterOptions="{stringResult :true,
                            searchOnEnter : true,
                            enableClear : true}" 
       >
         <sjg:gridColumn name="assigned_to"   index="issue_status" title="Assigned To" sortable="false"  search="true"
            searchtype="select"
            searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne'], dataUrl : '%{fillUser}'}"/> 
        </sjg:grid>
```

I want to have filters something like this link http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/searching/search_toolbar/default.php, Here The **shipcity** column having the drop-down list containing the list of cities, and based on the cities ,user can filter the data. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I made it work around just i have to create an action which can hold the list in **s:select** to do so ,

This is the action-result which hold the drop-down list

```
<s:select list="userList" theme="simple"
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Any"
          listKey="helper_name" listValue="helper_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<select` tag will not work with json list, you should use something like

`...searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne'], dataUrl : '%{fillUser}'}"/>`

**Step1:** 
Now map action url for`fillUser` , which returns a jsp(`selctbox.jsp`) on success.
 **Step2:**   In `selctbox.jsp` mention your
       `<sj:select name="myuserlist" key="" value=""..../>`i.e same as you have mention in `<sjg:gridcolumn` for dropdown.

You are done. Whenever you will load your grid. You will find your `fillUser` dropdown list.